# Using OUTPUT in sql to return the inserted row JAVASCRIPT/NODEJS/PG

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, pg

ultimately I am trying to call a callback function if my query is successfully inserted. 
I was thinking of trying to get the inserted row as a result and then test if the result exists and if it matches the inserted values then it was successful -> call my cb function. I'm getting an error that there's something wrong with my query. Is there a better query for this?

```
  var username = user.username;
  var password = user.password;
  var email = user.email;
  client.query(
    'INSERT INTO account (username, password, email) OUTPUT 
     INSERTED.username VALUES($1, $2, $3)',
    [username, password, email], (err, res) =>{
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        cb(err);
      }
      console.log(res); // this is undefined how do i test if it was inserted?
      client.end();
    });
```

the error that is thrown is "syntax error at or near \"OUTPUT\"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an invalid syntax for [Postgres Insert](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) to return a value. NO such thing as OUTPUT. Try

```
insert into account (username, password, email)  
     values($1, $2, $3) returning username;
```

But really why brother? If the insert doesn't work you can relay on Postgres to raise an exception; if a comparison of the returned value fails, where's the error? In the insert or the data sent, or data result compared to.

Comment: It works thanks. If there's no error thrown, then it 100% guaranteed it inserted correctly?

Comment: I've always worked under that assumption and have never had a problem with it. At least if I send the correct data.